# How to change stripe CardElement according to the country regulations?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to implememt stripe subscription.

Here is my react code:

```
const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();


 const onPayClickHandler = async (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            

            const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);
            

            const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: "card",
                card: cardElement,
            });

            if (error) {
                alert(error.message);
                return;
            }

            const response = await axios.post("/subscriptions", { plan: "price_1LzFhSSAy6HVqYxUjUW7uUd1", payment_method: paymentMethod.id });
           
            //Error handling code........... 
           
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

Here is the jsx part:

```
<div className="SubsCard">
     <div className="SubsCardTitle">Enter card details</div>
          <CardElement />
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={onPayClickHandler}>
                 Pay
          </Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the `Pay` button I can see that my `stripe customer id` is being generated but then I get an error saying `Error: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address`.

How do I add the `customer name` and `address`fields in `CardElement`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add the customer name and addressfields in CardElement

You generally wouldn't, since the CardElement only collects the basic number/expiry/CVC/postal code fields and nothing else.

The recommendations here would be:

- use Checkout as a hosted payment page from Stripe that will collect everything needed instead of directly integrating CardElement: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout
- if building this yourself, you will need to

  - add your own HTML inputs for collecting the customer's name and address
  - send those value to the backend server
  - supply them to the Customer Create or Update API when creating the Customer object on the backend. (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-name // https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-address )